# Can i use gravity as a multiplication factor to harness energy in this mechanism?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation

[image: Fig 1]

The Mechanism contains a pivoted mass of 1000kg and mass 10 kg that runs on the 1000 kg mass. Given the length of the 1000 kg mass is 10 meters, when the 10kg mass is moved (with external effort) to one side of this setup causing it to tilt and hence give a reaction force on pistons (which is large due to reaction force of total system ). My question is can I use this setup to harness the effect of gravity by giving a small energy to move 10 kg mass and harnessing great energy at the plungers?

Comment: The energy that you will get moving the 10kg from right to left will be $E = m g h$ where m is 10kg, g = ~9.8, h = the change in height on the left side. Assuming that all you have to do is to slide the 10kg to pass the middle and the let it slide on the "hill" you will need only a kinetic energy = mgh + friction loses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but there is no net energy gain. You only retrieve the energy that was needed to build that setup. It is like releasing the arrow of a crossbow: First you load the sytsem with energy, then release it with only a little effort.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to "amplify" the force from the plungers, bit it's not particularly helpful.

Aziraphale already provided an answer with a good point, setting up that system would require energy (and definitely a lot more than you get for running the piston once).

To isolate another issue, let's assume that somehow this has already been set up like this by nature (super unrealistic, only using it to illustrate a point).  You would still only be able to run this system once and get energy gain.

After that you would need to raise the mass back up if you want to use this again.  Best case scenario it will require the same energy as you could get from the potential energy to lift the mass back.  When you consider losses like friction and air resistance you come out losing energy.

Comment: So the 1000kg has no effect? Won't the reaction forces be more than the effort put to move the 10 kg block to one side?

Comment: @AbinAustin if it's balanced on the scale it shouldn't contribute, the only unbalanced moment comes from the 10 kg mass.